# How to Track Mobile Device Rotation in Unity

Tags: mobile, game-physics, unity-game-engine, screen-rotation

I am trying to make a 2D mobile game where the game's gravity changes as the device is rotated.  However, the only relevant input that I can find in the Unity Docs is [DeviceOrientation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html), which doesn't help me because it is an enum with only 7 possible values.  Is there any way to capture *continuous* changes in rotation, using Unity's scripting engine?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question on the UnityAnswers forum.  To future Googlers that land here, you can check out the [answer I got there](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1153340/how-to-track-small-changes-in-mobile-device-rotati.html#answer-1153515).